# Strange BeautifulSoup soup.findAll error: not working within functions

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to build a pretty simple scraper to harvest links as part of a crawler project. I've set up the following function to do the scraping:

```
import requests as rq 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getHomepageLinks(page):
    homepageLinks = []
    response = rq.get(page)
    text = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        homepageLinks.append(a['href'])
    return homepageLinks
```

I saved this file as "scraper2.py". When I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
>>> import scraper2 as sc
>>> sc.getHomepageLinks('http://washingtonpost.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "scraper2.py", line 9, in getHomepageLinks
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Now for the odd part: If I try to debug the code and just print the response, it works fine:

```
>>> response = rq.get('http://washingtonpost.com')
>>> text = response.text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> for a in soup.findAll('a'):
...     print(a['href'])
... 
https://www.washingtonpost.com
#
#
http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/
https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/
http://www.washingtonpost.com/sports/
http://www.washingtonpost.com/local/
http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/
http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/
...
```

If I'm reading the error messages correctly, the problem is occurring with soup.findAll, but only when the findAll is part of a function. I'm sure I'm spelling it correctly (not findall or Findall, as many of the errors on here are), and I've tried a fix using lxml suggested on a previous post that didn't fix it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As a sanity check, `print(soup.findAll)` right before the line causing the error. Does it print `None`? If so, what does `print(soup)` and `print(type(soup))` print?

Comment: Try using `soup.find_all('a')` instead of `soup.findAll('a')`

Comment: Ah, sorry about the blank import. Vestige of some old code that I didn't fully delete for posting. Editing now.

Comment: print(type(soup)) returns "<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>" when going manually. Running it as a function throws an error before it can print.

Comment: I tried the find_all, but nothing changed. From what I understand, they're interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your for-loop with the following:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    url = a.get("href")
    if url != None:
        homepageLinks.append(url)
```